# How to get user total commit number of all repositories on GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

For now I am trying this API (just randomly picked an id from a project)

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/3199253/repository/contributors
```

And I find that the commit number is always 1 while it is more than 1 on the contributor page. Meanwhile, the list is not completed and a lot of people are not on the returned result.

I checked the documentation and it doesn't seem like I need to paging it or I have the option to do so.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#contributors

Please let me know if there's any better way to count all commits of a user on GitLab. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Just found a related issue on Gitlab here:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/233119

Looks like the commit count will always be 1 due to a bug at the moment?

UPDATE: For now I am scanning the list of commits and matching them with the current user with a for loop (they said it has better performance than map()). Guess that would consume unnecessary API call usage.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? The bug issue was closed some time ago.

Comment: @Arty-chan Unsure if it is a completed solution yet. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/238226

Comment: ah interesting, agree that removing the differences from the API isn't really a solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I've managed to get it :

1. Download the [python-gitlab package](https://pypi.org/project/python-gitlab/)

   ```bash
   python3 -m pip install python-gitlab
   ```
2. Update the following script for the **targetusername** and a valid private token. Then run it :

   ```py
   import gitlab

   username = "targetusername"
   git_url = "https://gitlab.com/"
   gl = gitlab.Gitlab(git_url, "***********")

   projects = gl.projects.list()
   all_projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
   nb_projects = len(all_projects)

   # Get the user ID by username
   user = gl.users.list(username=username)[0]
   user_name = user.name
   user_id = user.id
   print(f"Checking for user {username} (#{user_id})")

   total_commits = 0
   i = 0
   while i < nb_projects:
       project = gl.projects.get(all_projects[i].id)
       print(f"Checking project {i}/{nb_projects} : {project.name}...")
       # Filter commits by author ID
       default_branch = project.default_branch
       project_branches = project.branches.list(get_all=True)

       for branch in project_branches:
           branch_name = branch.name
           branch_commits = project.commits.list(ref_name=branch.name, get_all=True)
           for commit in branch_commits:
               total_commits += (
                   1
                   if commit.author_name == user_name or commit.author_name == username
                   else 0
               )

       i += 1

   print(f"Total number of commits for {username} : {total_commits}")
   ```